# Installation failed in installing SQL Server 2008 SP3 on windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

[image]

[image]

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2014-12-11 10:02:32
  End time:                      2014-12-11 10:39:26
  Requested action:              Install
  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141211_095946\Detail.txt
  Exception help link:           http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%3fLinkId%3d20476%26ProdName%3dMicrosoft%2bSQL%2bServer%26EvtSrc%3dsetup.rll%26EvtID%3d50000%26ProdVer%3d10.0.5500.0%26EvtType%3d0x88792597%400xBB814387

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Vista
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     Philippines
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008
  SQLProductFamilyCode:          {628F8F38-600E-493D-9946-F4178F20A8A9}
  ProductName:                   SQL2008
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  Installation location:         c:\add633e5dea06a76a74be944ce77\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          EXPRESS

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       3

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      False
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141211_095946\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CUSOURCE:                      
  ENABLERANU:                    True
  ERRORREPORTING:                True
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PCUSOURCE:                     c:\add633e5dea06a76a74be944ce77\PCUSOURCE
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:          
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  True
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141211_095946\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141211_095946\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

i found 3 detail.txt. I tried to also install the management studio express but failed.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ivk5ttclk3o3v9/Detail.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/373ti53cvssqesu/Detail1.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdpzhntusrn1u56/Detail2.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting detailed logs As far as I can read logs and with my experience with SQL Server installation the error here is because your account does not have necessary rights to perform some registry actions.

My first question would be did you made sure you are installing SQL Server with administrator account. Even if account is domain admin make sure you add that account as local administrator on windows machine on which you are installing SQL Server.

**Always**right click on setup file and select run as administrator.

Before proceeding for re-installation again please read [THIS SUPPORT ARTICLE](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562?wa=wsignin1.0). make sure you meet all requirements as described in the support article

**Reason**

Below is some extract from details.txt file you posted

> Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:     Message:
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:         **Attempted to perform an unauthorized
>   operation.**
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:     Data:
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:       WatsonData = Microsoft SQL Server
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:     Inner exception type:
>   **System.UnauthorizedAccessException**
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:         Message:
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:                 Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation.
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:         Stack:
>
> 2014-12-11 10:38:04 Slp:                 at
>   System.Security.**AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType
>   resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections
>   accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultS**d)

The whole Log is filled with security exceptions and it was when SQL Server installation tried to access Reg key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server.

**Workaround**

A work around in below scenario might be

1. Go to run Type Regedit and registry hive will open Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server and then Right Click on Microsoft SQL Server Below screen will appear

[image]

Click on permission and then on page that occurs make sure you account is there if it is not there add you account and click on check box full control and then click on apply. It would take some time and then click ok.

2. Go to add remove program and remove all components related to SQL Server 2008. Make sure you completely uninstall SQL server from add remove program.
3. Right click on setup file and select Run As Adminsitrator to start installation again.
4. Please read [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000257?wa=wsignin1.0) and include workaround mentioned in Resolution section

**Additional Information**

If you face issue while uninstallation where by normal method you cannot uninstall SQL Server or uninstallation is giving error you can use below method to remove registry keys related to SQL Server. ONLY USE THIS MESSAGE AS LAST OPTION WHEN YOU HAVE MESSED UP WITH UNINSTALLATION. DELETING REGISTRY KEYS MIGHT CAUSE INCONSISTENCY. Use this on your own risk I have personally used this many times and works well DONT USE IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE INSATNCE. If you have messed up things and dont want to use below method you can raise a case with Microsoft

1. Uninstall the existing SQL Server  and all the components from the add remove program.
2. [Backup the registry](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/back-up-registry#1TC=windows-7)
3. Delete the following keys using regedit:
   --HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
   --HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer
4. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and delete all the sub-keys referencing SQL Server.
5. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services and delete all the keys referencing SQL Server.
6. Rename all the SQL Server folders in the computer.
7. Reboot the machine.